# to count the total no. of line items related to particular PO in the abap programming

Tags: abap

Dear Sir,
Please give me a hint, or tell me the exact procedure to calculate the total no. of rows or you can say it as line items related to particular PO in the Internal Table, but please note that this is not like that to calculate the total number of lines Internal Tables.

Comment: can you post some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you want to get the total number of lines which contain a particular PO number (EBELN). One way you can do this (not very elegant) is by looping at the internal table only where your condition is met and then reading the SY-INDEX variable.

```
LOOP AT itab TRANSPORTING NO FIELDS WHERE ebeln = 'your purchase order'.
ENDLOOP.

IF sy-subrc = 0. 
  total_lines = sy-index. 
ENDIF.
```

Another way is by moving the corresponding fields which meet your criteria to another internal table and using DESCRIBE TABLE to get the number of lines.

For more information read the ABAP keyword documentation